# How to make DUPLICATED ANSWERS wrong?

Tags: c++

i am making a word guessing game in c++ (im new at programming btw) im just gonna ask how can i make the "already-answered" answers as wrong and cant get points from the same word again? here's my current code...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    int firstQPoint, secondQPoint, thirdQPoint, mane;
    char yourChoice, levelChoice, goBack;
    string yourFirstAnswer, yourSecondAnswer, yourThirdAnswer;

gameMenu:
    cout << "\t GUESS THE WORD GAME";
    cout << "\t\n\n MADE BY GROUP FIVE";
    cout << "\t\t\n\n     1. PLAY | ENTER \"1\" TO PLAY ";
    cout << "\t\t\n\n     2. QUIT | ENTER \"2\" TO QUIT ";
    cout << "\t\t\n\n     3. RULES | ENTER \"3\" TO SEE THE RULES";
    cout << "\t\t\n\n     What Do You Want To Do : ";
    cin >> yourChoice;

    if (yourChoice == '1') {
        cout << "\t GUESS THE WORD GAME";
        cout << "\t\n\n MADE BY GROUP FIVE";
    selectALevel:
        cout << "\t\n\n OKAY, CHOOSE A LEVEL (1-3) : ";
        cin >> levelChoice;

        switch (levelChoice) {

        case ('1'):
            cout << "\t GUESS THE WORD GAME";
            cout << "\t\n\n MADE BY GROUP FIVE";
            cout << "\t\t\n\nGIVE 3 BODY PARTS THAT STARTS WITH LETTER \"T\"";
            cout << "1 : ";
            cin >> yourFirstAnswer;
            if (yourFirstAnswer == "TOE", "TONGUE", "TOOTH") {
                cout << "\n\n\t\tNICE, YOU GOT A POINT!";
                firstQPoint = 1 + 0;
            }

            cout << "2 : ";
            cin >> yourSecondAnswer;
            if (yourSecondAnswer == "TOE", "TONGUE", "TOOTH") {
                cout << "\n\n\t\tNICE, YOU GOT A POINT!";
                secondQPoint = 1 + firstQPoint;
            }
            cout << "3 : ";
            cin >> yourThirdAnswer;
            if (yourThirdAnswer == "TOE", "TONGUE", "TOOTH") {
                cout << "\n\n\t\tNICE, YOU GOT A POINT!";
                thirdQPoint = 1 + secondQPoint;
            }

            break;
        case ('2'):
            break;
        case ('3'):
            break;
        default:
            goto selectALevel;
        }
    }

    else if (yourChoice == '3') {
        do {
            cout << "\t GUESS THE WORD RULES";
            cout << "\t\t\n\n1. ONLY USE UPPERCASE LETTERS";
            cout << "\t\t\n\n1. ONLY USE SINGULAR WORDS";
            cout << "\t\t\n\n ENTER \"1\" TO GO BACK : ";
            cin >> goBack;
            if (goBack == '1') {
                goto gameMenu;
            }
        } while (goBack != '1');
    }

    else if (yourChoice == '2') {
        cout << "\t\t\n\n          Okay, Goodbye!";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

i tried the longer way, where i will manually code it like this

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{

    int number, again;

    cout << "give 2 number";
    cin >> number;

    cout << "again :";
    cin >> again;

    if (number == 1 && again == 2) {
        cout << "correct";
        else if (number == 2 && again == 1)
        {
            cout << "correct";
        }
    }
}
```

but it's very hard since im working with too many combinations! thanks in advance for answering!

Comment: add the already used answers to a `std::set`?

Comment: `if (yourSecondAnswer == "TOE", "TONGUE", "TOOTH")` -- This is not how you test if `yourSecondAnswer` is equal to any of those values.  If you look at your C++ book as to how an `if` statement works, you will not see anything looking like what you have there.  Unfortunate for you, it is valid code, but does **not** do what you think it does.

Comment: Another bit of advice -- write *small* programs that tests out the various aspects of what you are trying to do.  Writing programs with extensive I/O, menus, prompts, and any sort of things that add nothing just adds noise.  Something [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/sW1socP34) is what you should have started out with.

Comment: And last `goto gameMenu;` -- as soon as you did that, you've reduced the number of persons willing to help you significantly.  Instead of `goto`, use structured programming techniques, such as `while` loops, `for` loops, make things functions instead of stuffing everything in `main`, etc.  Few persons will want to untangle a mess of code that is riddled with `goto` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Inside each switch case you can make a loop to repeat the question if the word is wrong.

At the beginning of the switch (before the loop) you can create an empty list where you will store every answer they give.

In the end you only need to make a function that goes through that same list and checks if a word is inside it or not.

Comment: ...where "list" should be taken to mean something generic like "collection" or "container" or just "data structure", and not necessarily a `std::list` specifically.  Probably a `std::unordered_set`, I think might be a good specific choice.  In which case "goes through that same list" might be better worded as just "checks if a word is inside it or not" because "goes through" may suggest some kind of hand-rolled linear search, which is not necessary because _set_ has a fast `contains` method.

Comment: I was thinking "pseudo-code-wise" and not precisely in C++, but yes that was my idea